# How to pass ampersand to phpBB from HTML

Tags: html, phpbb, phpbb3, ampersand

I need to access this topic in phpBB:

```
http://forum.cadec-online.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=235
```

from HTML. If I put this in HTML:

```
<a href="http://forum.cadec-online.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&amp;t=235">text</a>
```

...then, phpBBB does not understands it.

Here is the live page:

```
http://help.cadec-online.com/UserManualEN/sect0012.html
```

Comment: It works for me. `text` is a link to a topic named 'API'

Comment: Could you please check the live page?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<a href="http://forum.cadec-online.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&amp;t=235">text</a>
```

you need to have

```
<a href="http://forum.cadec-online.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=235">text</a>
```

You do use entity (`&amp;`) if you want to pass ampersand only, which is not the case (value of `f` is not `3&` but just `3`).

Comment: but actually in the html file I have to write &amp; for only & to show up in the browser! correct?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<a href="http://forum.cadec-online.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&amp;amp;t=235">http://forum.cadec-online.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&amp;t=235</a>
```

to this:

```
 <a href="http://forum.cadec-online.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=235">http://forum.cadec-online.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&amp;t=235</a>
```